# Angular2 with LOCAL authentication instead of server-based

Tags: node.js, authentication, angular

I have an Angular2 application which requires an username/password authentication in order to work. Now, I am doing this via JWTs with a nodejs server using mongodb, it works pretty well.

I was thinking: in my application, I don't need to add/delete users, there will only be 2 roles: administrator and normal user, obviously the admin can do things that the user can't. Since I don't need a user management, is there a way I can remove my nodejs server and store the logged user in the angular application? The thing is that is making me doubt is that, if I store the password in the application, a user with a little bit of experience could change the javascript objects at runtime and set the admin password to gain admin priviledges.

What do you think?

Comment: unless you use a server, anything that you place into the client will be unsecured and accessible to anybody.

Answer (score 0):

A save client-side-only-authentication is **not** possible. A difference between client-side and server-side web application code is that the  user can execute the code on the client-side without permission. This means that anything your application can do using JavaScript, a user just by opening the Developer Tools in her browser.

A lightweight option is a dedicated back-end authentication. Services like for example *Firebase* or *Google OAuth* offer simple ways to authenticate users to your application.